# How to create a T-SQL function to read values which have been updated as part of the same [update] transaction

Tags: sql-server

I need to use a function in an update of several records.

How to make a T-SQL function read values which have been updated during that update?

Below I created a simple example demonstrating what I get.

**My example**: table has `Category` column and I build code based on a category. Function finds the last one withing the category + 1. Or 10000 if it is the first record.

It would work just fine if update is a single record, but updates all records with the same value otherwise.

Below is working code:

```
CREATE TABLE Tbl
(
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Category CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    Code INT NULL
)

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetNextAvailableCode
     (@Category CHAR(1))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @MaxCode INT

    SELECT @MaxCode = MAX(Code) 
    FROM dbo.Tbl
    WHERE Category = @Category

    SET @MaxCode = ISNULL(@MaxCode + 1, 10000);

    RETURN @MaxCode
END;
GO

INSERT INTO Tbl (Id, Category)
VALUES (1, 'A'), (2, 'A'), (3, 'A'),
       (4, 'B'), (5, 'B'),
       (6, 'C'), (7, 'C'), (8, 'C'), (9, 'C')

SELECT * FROM Tbl

UPDATE dbo.Tbl
SET Code = dbo.GetNextAvailableCode(Category)
WHERE Code IS NULL

SELECT * FROM Tbl
GO 

DROP TABLE Tbl;
DROP FUNCTION dbo.GetNextAvailableCode;
```

Here is the result I'm getting:

[image: here is result I'm getting]

What I'd like to get is the following:

[image]

But it's possible only if next function call can see **already changed** values...

Any idea how to implement such thing?

Comment: This is by design that the function sees the values pre-change. A spool is added for "Halloween protection" specifically to prevent your desired effect. You will need to change your approach and do it without the function. e.g. by precalculating the desired result in advance without relying on reading the table mid update

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about my design flaw...

Answer (score 1):

Since it is not possible to use function to achieve the desired effect, I re-wrote the update to be used without function and it worked!

Here is the update which produces the result I need:

```
;WITH data AS (
    SELECT Id, Category, Code, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Category ORDER BY Id) AS RowNo 
        FROM dbo.Tbl
        WHERE Code IS NULL
)
, maxData AS (
    SELECT Category, MAX(Code) AS MaxCode 
        FROM dbo.Tbl
        GROUP BY Category

)
UPDATE S
    SET Code = ISNULL(T.MaxCode, 10000) + S.RowNo
    FROM data S JOIN maxData T ON T.Category = S.Category
    WHERE S.Code IS NULL
```

Result: [image]